# Bootstrap input group pushing table beyond screen width in Internet Explorer

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I am building a website using Bootstrap, and to both consistently style the fields and indicate units of input I make heavy use of input groups. At one point, I had to create an edit form in a table. I considered putting it in a Bootstrap grid, but since the data itself is really tabular, I went and made it a `table`:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 32px;"></th>
                    <th style="width: 7em;"></th>
                    <th style="width: 7em;">Test 1</th>
                    <th style="width: 10em;">Test 2 </th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Test 3</th>
                    <th style="width: 10em;">Test 4
                    <th style="width: auto;">Test 5 </th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Alternative 1</th>
                    <th style="width: 10em;">Probability 1</th>
                    <th style="width: auto;">Alternative 2</th>
                    <th style="width: 10em;">Probability 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr  class="shareEditor">
                <input  type="hidden" value="1" />
                <input  type="hidden" value="7" />
                <input  type="hidden" value="0" />
                <input  type="hidden" value="2" />
                <td>
                </td>
                 <td>Test</td>
                <td>
            <input  type="hidden" value="True" /><input  type="hidden" value="1" />Test</td>
    <td><input class="form-control"  type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input value="0" class="form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-append input-group-text">m3</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <!-- Omitted -->
    </tr>            
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Edge: the input fields scale their widths so that the table fits on the width of the page, for as long as feasible. See this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/sozetategi and try resizing the screen.

But Internet Explorer 11 wants to make the input groups of a fixed width, pushing the columns beyond the widths specified in the `th` and making the table scroll horizontally even when maximized on my 1900x1200 resolution screen.

[image: Chrome - expected behaviour - all columns are visible even on non-maximized window]

[image: Internet Explorer 11 - inputs are forced to a certain width so not all columns are visible and page scrolls horizontally]

Is this a bug in Bootstrap, or do I need some alternative classes to make IE behave properly here?

Comment: Have you tried `.table-responsive` Bootstrap class?

Comment: @Senthe that does not change anything. http://jsbin.com/besagajopa/1/edit

Comment: @CompuChip, Flexbox does not work perfectly in IE 11, especially the flex-wrap. Try thinking of another way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-group > .custom-file, .input-group > .custom-select, .input-group > .form-control {
width: 1vw;
max-width: 1vw;
}
```

Add above CSS in ur stylesheet and customize `vw`. this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by "customize `vw`"? I can fiddle with the number until the input fields fill up the available space but then (a) they will not be as wide as for example the `input-group-text` that I have in one of the columns and (b) more importantly, things will start to look weird as soon as I resize the window.

Comment: @CompuChip i meant vary the `vw` to change viewport width. And to control the view while resizing window, use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually default `table` behaviour. They are a pain in the ass for responsive webdesign.. A solution is to use [Responsive Bootstrap Tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables) like so:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
```

Here is your working JS Bin with resizeable tables: https://jsbin.com/ginuditoke/1/edit?html,output